# How to find out what cities you already have a trading post in?

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a way to find out what trading posts you already have? I have lots of cities and want to make sure I have created a trading post in all of them.

Also when is a trading post created in a domestic city and a foreign city? I understand that sending a trade route to a foreign city creates a trading post but domestically does it create a trading post in both cities automatically or how does that work? Also if there is a way to find out with a mod share that too please.

Answer (score 4):

When selecting a route for a trader you can see a trading post icon next to the name of cities you have a trading post in.
You can create trading posts in any city by letting the route to that city run to completion on its own.

Comment: Maybe an off question but does having a trading post in your domestic city do anything for you besides increase distance? (I know with Rome you get +1 gold) If you start a trade route in a domestic city does both cities get a trade post? Or only the destination domestic city?